# Blender models not being detected by Physics.Raycast()

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclicklistener, blender

I'm relatively new to Unity. I'm making a Chess Game. In the screenshot below, you see the following *GameObjects*:

1. 3D Planes as the squares.
2. Blender models for chess pieces.

For now, here's a very basic script I'm using to detect the clicked object and delete it (will add more functionality later).

```cs
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            //highlightPiece(hit.transform.gameObject, whiteSelectedTexture, false);
            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the GameObjects native to Unity (the plane objects making the squares) are detected by the ray cast but the blender models are not. This is confirmed by the screenshot since the closest object should be detected. The script ended up deleting the squares but not the chess pieces (which I actually plan to select and work on).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You surely haven't added a `Collider` to your imported Blender Objects.

Select every chess pieces and add a `BoxCollider` / `CapsuleCollider`.

By the way, I think you can remove the Collider of the chess plate.

Moreover, I highly recommand you to use layers when you raycast so as to be even more efficient. Check the following Unity article : https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-best-practices

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much! BTW my chess pieces are nested (I added an extra parent). Adding the `BoxCollider` to the parent did not work. Adding it to the sub object with the `Renderer` worked!

Comment: If you want to add to the parent, you may have to set the dimensions of the `BoxCollider` / `CapsuleCollider` by hand from the Inspector ![BoxCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/Inspector-BoxCollider.png)

Comment: Everything in this answer is correct and excellent, well done @Hellium, but you ***absolutely should not use*** a mesh collider: it's one of the most confusing things in Unity for totally new game hobbyists.